# How to Inject service instead of instantiating always with new Keyword in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using new instance always how to inject service to avoid using all the time new key word.

```
    use GuzzleHttp\Client;
    $auth = base64_encode('user:'.config('mailchimp.api_key'));
    //API URL
    $urll = "https://".config('mailchimp.data_center').".api.mailchimp.com/3.0/batches";
    //API authentication Header
    $headers = array(
        'Accept'     => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Basic '.$auth
    );
    $client = new Client();
    $req_Memeber = new Request('POST', $urll, $headers, $userlist);
    // promise
    $promise = $client->sendAsync($req_Memeber)->then(function ($res){
            echo "Synched";
        });
      $promise->wait();
```

Comment: have handle method and pass Client as dependency.

Comment: Could you please put the whole method or file?